# How to align rectangles with different width horizontally to center, but keeping the anchor point at the centre of each rectangle?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, geometry

For example, if I have 2 rectangles, the anchor point is in the centre of the rectangle, one the width is 6 (Red), another is 2 (blue), I want to align them horizontally to the centre like this:

[image]

So that the position(also the centre and anchor point) of whole structure is at the origin, the red rectangle should be placed at (-1,0), and the blue rectangle should be placed at (3,0).

This example can be solved by graph and divided into 1 unit segments, but how about if I have arbitrary numbers of rectangles with different width?

[image]

How to find the position of each rectangle which the anchor point of each rectangle is at the centre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum the widths of all the rectangles and then divide by 2. This is the distance from the left side of the left-most rectangle to center.

Then for each rectangle, compute the distance from the left side of the left-most rectangle to the rectangle's center point. Subtract this from the first number to find the offset of the rectangle's center point from the center.

Pseudo-code:

Find distance from the left side of the left-most rectangle to center:

```
int i;
float sum = 0;
for(i = 0; i < rectangle_count; i++)
    sum += rectangles[i].width;
centerpoint = sum / 2.0;
```

Compute offset of each rectangle from center:

```
sum = 0.0;
for(i = 0; i < rectangle_count; i++)
{
    // compute offset for this rectangle relative to center:
    rectangles[i].offset = (sum + (rectangles[i].width / 2.0)) - centerpoint;

    sum += rectangles[i].width;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there are n small rectangles and call them r<sub>0</sub>, r<sub>1</sub>, ..., r<sub>n-1</sub>. Furthermore, let's assume we're laying them out left to right. Let's call the larger rectangle formed by putting them all end to end R, and assume we have a function w(r) that computes the width of a rectangle.

We know that the left side of R will have an x-coordinate of -w(R)/2. That will also be the x coordinate of r<sub>0</sub>, let's call this x-coordinate l<sub>0</sub>. You know that the x-coordinate of the left hand side of r<sub>1</sub> will be moved over by one width of r<sub>0</sub>. In other words, l<sub>1</sub> = w(r<sub>0</sub>) + l<sub>0</sub>. Likewise, you know that the x-coordinate of the left hand side of r<sub>2</sub> will be at l<sub>2</sub> = w(r<sub>1</sub>) + l<sub>1</sub>. In general, l<sub>i</sub> = w(r<sub>i-1</sub>) + l<sub>i-1</sub>.

In plain english, you're calculating the position of the left hand side of the first rectangle and adding its width to find the left hand side of the next one and repeating that process until you know the position of the left hand side of every rectangle.

Now the only difficulty is to find the x-coordinate of the center of each rectangle. But you already know the x-coordinate of left hand side for each one, so just move over half its width to the right. That is c<sub>i</sub> = l<sub>i</sub> + w(i)/2, where c<sub>i</sub> is the x-coordinate of the center of r<sub>i</sub>.